# How to inspect the http traffic created by other applications on local iis?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, iis, fiddler

I'm working on a windows server. the iis log shows that there are lots of http requests (port 80) sent from an application (App_A) running on the server. The iis entry looks like

> 2015-12-03 18:04:49 fe80::c57a:3770:b151:47d4%10 POST /powershell
>   PSVersion=2.0 80 myDomain\myService fe80::c57a:3770:b151:47d4%10
>   Microsoft+WinRM+Client 500 0 64 0 1999 1558

I'm wondering whether there is a way to see exactly what this request send?

I start Fiddler 4, however, it does not show any traffic, but from the iis log file, it does show the traffic.

So, the question, how can I catch the traffic in this case?

*PS, I do not own App_A, so I could not change anything in it.

Thanks

Comment: Go read this: [Using Fiddler with IIS](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-fiddler-with-iis/)

Comment: Definitely, old good [Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865), or the new [Microsoft Message Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226)

Comment: Another option is [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap). It can capture traffic this is internal to Windows, like from a VM to the host. You use Wireshark to analyze it's output.

Comment: What is the app, and what network stack does it use?